# Phalcon PHP - Get all permitted resources

Tags: php, acl, phalcon

I am using **ACL** in **Phalcon PHP** (Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory).
I would like to know if it is possible to get **all resources / actions** a specific role is permitted to do / to access?

This code checks if a specific role is permitted to perform a specific action on a specific resource:

```
$acl->isAllowed("Guests", "Customers", "create");
```

I don't want to run over all resources and actions and check permissions with the code above. I need it all at once.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think you need to implement an own adapter for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use \Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory as Acl;

class CustomAcl extends Acl {

    public function getAllowed($role) {
        $accessList = array();
        foreach ($this->_access as $resource => $permission) {
            $resourceRole = explode("!", $resource);
            if ($resourceRole[0] != $role) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($permission == 1) {
                $accessList[] = $resource;
            }
        }
        return $accessList;
    }

}
```

This would return all the roles in the form of an array:

```
array (
    0 => 'role!resource!action',
    1 => 'role!resource!action',
    ...
    n => 'role!resource!action'
)
```

the same way they are stored inside the acl.